# GIT merge a branch from one repo to a branch of another repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

Having a bit a GIT problem when trying to merge a branch from one repo to the branch of another repo. The nut of the problem is that once the process is finished and I try to push to the branch I am working on GIT errors stating I can only push my own commits to this repository.

The steps taken so far :

```
git clone <my_repo> - This contains commits and changes I have made 
git remote add fork <forked_repo> This contains commits and changes made by a work mate 
git fetch <forked_repo>/<forked_branch> 
git checkout <my_branch> 
git merge <forked_repo>/<forked_branch>
```

--- resolve conflicts

```
git commit
git status
    Your branch is ahead of <my_branch> by 11 commits

git log
    HEAD < my commit
    HEAD-1 < work mates commit
    HEAD-2 < my commit
    HEAD-3 < my commit
    HEAD-4 < work mates commit
```

and so on.

```
git push
    remote: You can only push your own commits in this repository
    remote: Commit <SHA> was committed by work mate
```

I know it is giving me the error because my stack of commits contains commits by my work mate. What I am expecting is that I can use the merge function to produce a set of code that is both their current branch and mine and then push this new code base to my branch.

The easy fix seems to be turn off the pre-receive hook and allow commits made by other people but I feel like I am not doing something correctly, It feels like this sis something most people would be doing without having to turn off the commit protection?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to merge the history of the other branch or just the code? If you don't care about the history, you could just merge the changes by using `git merge --squash <forked_repo>/<forked_branch>`

Comment: It would be nice to retain the history so that in the future if someone was reviewing the previous changes they would understand how it got to where it is now.

If that's not possible then merge --sqaush sounds like it would do the job, Are there any gotchas with using --squash ?

Comment: A pre-receive hook that only lets you push your own commits is unusual and, as your discovering, gets in the way of collaboration. I'd say just turn it off.

Comment: If you need to retain the history without disabling the hook, your mate would have to push his own commits to your repo first. Otherwise, you would need to rewrite the branch history so that you become the author of his commits. That's a bit of a hassle. `--squash` allows you to create one or several commits from the changes. The one "gotcha" is the loss of the history, or the fact that you're not truly merging the branches, so your mate can't easily pull in your work back to his branch without running into the same problems.

Comment: I also agree with @Schwern that this hook is going to be painful if this is a regular part of your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, Good to know that rather than getting the process wrong it is an unusual server configuration causing the problem.